# Javascript - Dim/Darken canvas except for one section

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency

Using Vanilla JS, I'm looking to do something like in the image below whereby most of the canvas is darkened except for a specific section (oval shaped preferably).

[image]

I can darken the canvas easily by drawing a semi-transparent color at the front, but I'm not sure how to achieve the undimmed section.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the undimmed section is not actually 'undimmed' it just has a lighter color.

Does stacking two layers solve your problem - use the dimming layer, and then apply a white oval over the section to be emphasized?

If not, you can lay a transparent oval instead, which will clear the section, as per DrC's suggestion.

Comment: Not a white oval, but a transparent oval.  I've done this in the past with a second canvas layer overlaying the first filled with a semi-transparent grey (alpha=0.75) and then clearing the cutout.   Used it for tutorials.

Comment: Yeah used it for demonstration purposes, but would like to avoid going with that approach if possible